# ¿Como cambiar el tamaño o ancho de un Tab o pestaña en PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

He decidido empezar a utilizar PyQt5 para la creación de ventanas con un enfoque más moderno, aunque he tenido problemas especificamente al usar el control de pestañas `QTabWidget()` ya que he utilizado la función de estilos `setStyleSheet()` para cambiar la apariencia del ancho y alto del control de pestañas `QTabWidget()`, aunque al funcionar, el ancho del texto es delimtado o el espacio entre el texto y la pestaña es limitado e impide la modificación cortando el texto y dejando una mala apariencia de las pestañas.

Esto es lo que he intentando usando la función `setStyleSheet()`:

```
tabs = QTabWidget(windowOptions) # Tenga en cuenta que windowOptions es el padre o raíz de la ventana.

tabs.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab {width: 50px}")
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Nótese que al utilizar los estilos se cambia el parámetro de ancho en píxeles aunque limitando la salida del texto estático en general en el control de pestañas.

Sin embargo esta solución la he intentado utilizar de distintas forma pero al parecer esto es predeterminado de los controles de pestañas y los comportamientos son administrador por parte de PyQt5, sin embargo, de qué manera puedo retirar esa limitación del texto en las pestañas. Agradecería cualquier solución al respecto.

**Nota:** Al utilizar estilos al paracer modifican el aspecto global del control mas no cada pestaña en específico como lo puede notar en la imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En su caso usar hojas de estilos puede de alguna manera cambiar el comportamiento de las pestañas y hasta incluso propiedades como el borde, espaciado o `padding` y colores de fondo, entre otros. Por tanto, su problema específicamente se encuentra en usar el método `width`, esto cambia el tamaño de la pestaña en píxeles pero altera el texto.

La solución sería utilizar el parámetro `padding` dentro de la hoja de estilos, esto cambiará el tamaño de la pestaña y su relación con el texto o el espaciado.

```
tabs.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab {padding: 6px; height: 13px}")
```

> Nota: Aunque se cambie el tamaño del espaciado, esto cambiará el estilo del control de pestañas a un estilo antiguo o de versiones anteriores con relación al administrador de ventanas o a la librería en específico. Por lo cual usted puede cambiar ciertos parámetros del aspecto como lo mencioné anteriormente

Comment: Gracias por responder, su respuesta ayuda a mi problema, se cambia el ancho de los tabs y mantiene la relación del texto y funciona bien aunque no entiendo también porqué se cambia el estilo de tabs a un estilo antiguo pero de igual forma me sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías haber puesto un código mínimo y funcional para ver como se ejecuta, igual te muestro como lo hago, aunque para eso no uso una hoja de estilos:

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.apariencia()
         
    def apariencia(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Qtabwindow')
        self.resize(677,700)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif", 12))
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 675, 699))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(tab1(), "Texto muy largo")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(tab2(), "txt")
        self.show()

class tab1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
               
class tab2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
      
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = Principal()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

No hay nada para explicar un widget para el formulario y uno para el tab, después uso los métodos propios para modificarlos.
sino es esto, es que muchas veces no entiendo lo que buscan.

Comment: Antes que todo gracias por responder, la respuesta no contesta mi problema aún, por lo cual claramente mi pregunta está enfocada a reducir el espacio o el ancho entre el texto y la pestaña, por lo cual el mínimo ejemplo está expuesto mediante el intento de usar hojas de estilos, está pregunta se enfatiza en un problema en particular. Su respuesta es viable en el caso de crear un control de pestañas o `QTabWidget()` aunque ya eso lo tengo claro, por tanto si es posible puede suministar una respuesta que se adecude a mi pregunta o se enfoque en lo que yo le he mencionado, gracias.